Name of Sefer On Torah Temima
I was told about a sefer that was written about the Torah Temima I believe it was written by a Rabbi in Los Angeles during the lifetime of the author of the Torah Temima. The, I believe, shows how other sources already brought some of the explanations brought in the Torah Temima.
Can anyone identify that sefer?

Very good question. I once saw a vort in Torah Temimah without a source. Later I discovered that it was taken from Rabbenu Bachya.

It's by Rabbi Feldman, Meshivat Nafesh

@DoubleAA thanks. Couldn't locate it on hebrewbooks. Where is it available,  if at all.

@Yoreinu I've only ever seen the stand-alone original edition in print. This looks like a new edition that has it as footnotes with the TT https://www.chorev.co.il/%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%93-5-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D.htm

First 150 pages for free on Otzar Hachochmah. Someone should make this an answer.

The work in the OP question is called Meshivat Nafesh by R' Rabbi Moses J. Feldman (Yaakov Moshe Feldman). There is an article from the Jewish Press newspaper A Masterwork Completed – 84 Years Later by Hillel Fendel presenting the author and his peirush.
In addition, there is another work on Torah Temimah from the Admor m'Ozharov. Both are included in the new edition of Torah Temimah published by Chorev. It has the following features:

Rashi with Sifsei Chakhamim
Added nekudos on the peirushim.
Comments and sources on the page many improvements on the words of the author, even with sources from


peirush Meshivat Nafesh by Rabbi Moses J. Feldman (Yaakov Moshe Feldman) and
peirush of the Admor m'Ozharov


Commentary from machaber "Gishmei Berakha" on 5 megilos.
Indexes on discussed issues and authors.

